# Installing flask dependencies takes long on aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, autoscaling

I currently have auto-scaling setup so that once my existing instances reach high usage, new nodes are created on which my flask application is deployed and run.

The issue I am having is that deployment takes a while (7minsish) because I have many dependencies in my requirements.txt and it takes a while to stand up a node and install all of them.

How can I quicken this process?

Comment: I'm not sure but check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html I think this would let you have an image with everything already in place.

Comment: Do you install a lot of libraries that don't offer wheels? Compiling your own could help speed up. At the end of the day, though, building an AMI would bring the biggest win.

Answer (score 0):

After everything has been setup on your instance bake an AMI from the fully ready instance. Use the AMI ID in the autoscaling configuration. That way any instance that is spun-up by the autoscaling group will be ready with all the required software.

Comment: My concern here is that we deploy our code frequently so setting up an AMI may not be suitable as our codebase changes very often, but its our dependencies which rarely change